# Как можно сохранить дизайн страницы?

Tags: веб-дизайн, сервисы

Бывает встретишь интересную страницу и хочется её дизайн сохранить себе на будущее. File -> Save Page As... сохраняет криво, эффекты не работают в сохраненном файле. Может быть есть какие-нибудь сервисы, позволяющие получить рабочую копию страницы?

Comment: Думаю, никак. Я когда-то хотел такое сделать - не очень-то и вышло. Хотя теперь я представляю, как можно действовать. Ещё был вопрос по теме на английском SO (не мой), но его не поняли и сильно заминусовали - не уверен, цел ли он ещё. В любом случае, в тот момент ответы там были все мимо.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, кажется, не в тему.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, он просил _снепшот_, а ты дал ссылку на _скриншот_. Разница в том, что я понимаю, что он хочет html со стилями, а ты предлагаешь картинку. Дальше, онлайн-сервисы неспособны сохранить текущее состояние, они могут только сами открыть страницу и в таком виде скриншот и сделать. Ну и наконец, для оскриншочивания есть полно браузерных расширений - зачем тогда нужен онлайн-сервис?

Comment: @Qwertiy я не имел ввиду скриншот. Я имел ввиду сделать полную рабочую копию страницы вместе со скриптами, стилями и другими ресурсами. И чтобы всё работало автономно.

Comment: @abg, про разметку и стили я понял - самому иногда такое надо. А вот со скриптами - как бы браузер с ними и сохраняет, так что если не работает, то работать и не будет. Есть специальные программы для скачивания сайтов полностью, но функционирование скриптов после этого всё равно под вопросом. Например, скрипты могут делать ajax-запросы к БД - ты же не думаешь, что у тебя будет эта БД захардкожена в скрипте?

Comment: Некоторые сайты могут работать как оффлайновые приложения - файлы, которых им достаточно, перечислены в специальном манифесте. Вот такое должно быть несложно сохранить.